# Removing the year,month and day of datetime in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to edit the default date time, and remove its year,month,day and only display the hour minute and seconds, example:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

will become

```
00:00:00
```

Comment: Do you want to change the type of the column into a type that only stores time, or retain the `datetime` type but strip the date components of all existing values?

Comment: I only want to display the hours,minute and seconds. If possible I want it to be datetime

Comment: changing a data type is something you never should do. instead use the data type and format the output by the given sql functions. see here for more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I can't find the answer that I'm looking for from the link that you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL you can easily use one of its functions to extract from `DATETIME` columns the data you need for example:

```
SELECT TIME(my_datetime_column) FROM tableX
```

Would give you the `TIME` alone from your `DATETIME` column.

An alternative way would be to use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_datetime_column, '%H:%i:%s') FROM tableX
```

Which would use `DATE_FORMAT` function format the output with your predefined format of your `DATETIME` column.

[You have several other functions like `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR`, you can read more about it here...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)